# Intellisense stopped working for Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, intellisense

I have this simple code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Linq;
using GadNameSpace;


public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GadEntities db = new GadEntities();
        var images = db.Images.Where(x => x.isApproved == true).ToList();

        Repeater1.DataSource = images;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Now if I'm trying to edit this line:

```
var images = db.Images.  <--this is where intellisense is not working...
```

It worked before. Same file, same project, same Solution.
If I'm writing the code manually and run it, its working fine.
I tried start > cmd > "devenv /ResetSettings"
I tried to restart pc also.
**The problem is with Linq intellisense only! for anything else intellisense is working** fine...

Any good ideas?

Comment: try add "using System.Core;"

Comment: @KoViMa you sure about that?

Comment: You say 'only happens in Linq'  however I bet if you do this:

    `var ints = new[] {1, 2, 3};

    var twoOnly = ints.Where(i => i == 2);`

Then I'm sure intellisense will appear correctly?  Please try (in the same source file); then report back...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually this happens to me when a reference to `System.Data.Linq.dll` is missing from the module.

I bet you have your data context in yet another assembly where the reference is set correctly (so that the code works when you compile it) but in the same time the reference is missing from the web application (and thus VS does not show the intellisense).

Comment: I have this in my web.config: '        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>'

Comment: Is your project a web site or a web application? Why do you need two references (both 3.5 and 4.0)?

Comment: It is web application. Idont need them both. probably old setting. so I've erased it and now Im only with 4.0 ver and still the same problem

Comment: And did you add the reference to system.data.linq from References node in project tree?

Comment: I dont have References node in project tree: <img src="http://s18.postimage.org/zf3ta7ell/scrren.jpg"> my assemblies looks like that: <img src="http://s13.postimage.org/l1limgo2f/222222.jpg">

Comment: It is a web site then, not a web application. Could you try to create a new project of type "Web Application", add a reference to system.data.linq, add your data context and check if the intellisense works?

Comment: I opoened new web application--> Intellisense worked fine with Linq to EF. So I tried to download the entire website again from the web server (as I said it has compiled and ran just fine, and the iis is configured to NET 4.0), and when I ve opened it again the VS2010 shows a message "this site is running under .NET 3.5. do you want to change it to .Net 4 ?" I cliked yes and every thing is OK now with intellisense. When I compared the new web.config to the old one I noticed that all the assemblies of ver 3.5 has gone.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, reference of EntityFramework could be missing. Please make sure that the same exists in the project you're working on.