# How to remove LINQ extension methods from Intellisense?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, intellisense, extension-methods

Basically I want the opposite of this question: [Intellisense stopped working for Linq to Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580326/intellisense-stopped-working-for-linq-to-entities)

This is driving me mad since I downloaded VS 2022 and upgraded my projects to .NET 7

VS is placing `using System.Linq` in every file I create. I'm deleting this line. Sometimes it stops showing me the methods for a minute but then it starts to show them back, even there is no `using ...` . Whenever I implement `IEnumerable` the list is bloated with useless methods that distract me from work and slow me down...

For example I have a `List<Path>` (geometry) and I want extract sub range of it. I type ".sub" and the only entry showed in the list is `Sum<T>(Func<T, decimal>...)`, instead of proposing `GetRange(int, int)` (which is the name I forgot) and it takes a lot of time to find a method manually in such a big list. Doesn't feel very "Intelli" to me...

Why is this so intrusive and how do I stop it?

I tried removing `using` statements in file and unchecked "Implicit global usings" in project settings.

Comment: I don't know how to do that, but are you sure you want that? Many operations on lists are implemented as extension methods, so if these don't show up and you don't know them, you'll not find them.

Comment: I'm sure. I've programmed in C# for 6 years and I can count on my fingers how many times I used LINQ. It's slow an unhandy. For example I use some method on `List<T>` and what I get back is `IEnumerable<T>` so I can no longer access elements by index unless I convert it back to list... Whenever I tried to find a method for basic specific purpose (for example prefilling) I had to write my own method anyway because it was not there... Or I'm reading description of `Join` method and I have no idea what it says, and the signature is even more convoluted...

Comment: note that I think extension methods should appear both at the bottom of the list, and also with a unique icon. (can't remember for sure what it's like in VS though). if you see them at the top of the list, then there is nothing else found. hiding them would not help you in your example; you still would not find `GetRange` by typing `sub`.

Comment: @DaveCousineau not really: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1llZXxeTHMd4o9y1T-lRl7RODPS8VFmos/view?usp=sharing I would not find `GetRange` by typing `sub` but I would have like ~60 entries less to search in.

Comment: I think the down arrow is indicating extension method. I think you can click the method icon at the bottom that does not have the down arrow and that should show filter the list to just non-extension methods. (not 100% sure as I use Rider not VS these days.)

Comment: @DaveCousineau yes, I was just showing that they not appear at the bottom as you said. And as I said (see comment under PMF answer below) I don't want to hide all extension methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me, although probably because I have [resharper](/questions/tagged/resharper) installed (not sure how it looks without).

[image: Popup window]

The extension methods are listed after all the other methods, so searching is easier. Also, the small buttons at the bottom allow to filter by type. Left-clicking on the "Extension method" icon (the one with the down-arrow) shows only these, right clicking hides them. The choice is remembered between usages of the dropdown.

To hide suggestions from non-included namespaces (including linq extensions methods), but generally keep showing extension methods, there's an option under `Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Intellisense -> Show Elements from non-included namespaces`.

Comment: I'm aware of the buttons, however I DON'T want to exclude all extension methods. I just want the LINQ methods to be excluded (or simply any methods that are part of namespace I don't explicitly include with `using`). I'm writing lot of extension methods myself so this option is not very handy.

Comment: Oh, ok. What about Options->Text Editor -> C# -> Intellisense -> Show Elements from non-included namespaces? That sounds like it's the option you want.

Comment: Yup, It looks like it is the option. Edit your answer and I will accept it.