# Intellisense lists many unnecessary <Extention> methods for objects of type String?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

In my VB.Net 2019, the Intellisense auto-complete list is showing many unnecessary methods for objects of type `String`.

These methods all have the `<Extension>` attribute, as shown in the attached screenshot. Many of them seem to be data-related, such as Any, All, and Distinct. But others are not and seem wrong for String, such as Average, Count, and Intersect.

For this screenshot, I created a test-project, and removed everything from References except `System` and `Microsoft.VisualBasic`, and still the extension methods are there.

Where do these methods come from?

I understand I can click the buttons on the auto-complete list for `Properties` and `Methods` to show only those. But also I would like to understand where the extension methods are coming from for my own education.

[image]

Comment: `Average` is the only one you mentioned that I can't imagine ever using on a string.  It can be helpful to use e.g. `Select` or `Where` to do character-by-character processing.  I've used `Where` to strip non-whitespace control characters out of a string.

Comment: Weird that they're still there even after you strip out references though.  Is it an SDK-style project or an old-style project?  I just checked on an SDK-style project in VS 2022, and it seems like there are a set of default namespace imports (including `System.Linq` that can't be removed.

Comment: The test-solution is a Console App .Net Framework v4.7.2. I chose Console because I figured it would cut out the Windows Forms extras. But - @Craig's answer below seems to have nailed it.

Comment: Re "answer below seems to have nailed it"... sort of, I explained the root of where it's coming from, but there's still an unresolved question of why it's still getting pulled in even though you apparently removed the automatic import of `System.Linq`.

Comment: I fixed it! I will post my own answer in a moment to explain.

Answer (score 2):

You're seeing those extension methods because `String` implements `IEnumerable(Of Char)` and the `System.Linq` namespace is automatically imported as part of your project properties.  The methods you highlighted are standard Linq extension methods for anything that implements `IEnumerable(Of T)`.

You can see this if you look closely at the IntelliSense; note that it reads "<Extension> Function **IEnumerable(Of Char)**.Aggregate...".

You can control the automatic imports through the "References" ply in project properties (it's in the same place in both original and SDK style projects).  I believe `System.Linq` is one of the defaults.

Additionally, there are options settings where IntelliSense may "show items from unimported namespaces" (see Tools / Options / Text Editor) which may lead to the extension methods being shown even if you have removed `System.Linq` as a default import.  See the self-answer for more details on changing these option settings.

Comment: Wow. Thanks to your answer, I fixed it! You tipped me off to Linq, and I found something buggy going on. I will post my own answer to explain it.

Comment: @spinjector I think it's not buggy, exactly, but I'm not convinced of the value of the IntelliSense option you found.

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure either. But after an hour of clicking around between two systems, in both VB and C# projects, to precisely work out the solution, I think it's just badly implemented. Some things need to be improved: 1) remove the requirement to close/reopen the project to see the changes (see my self-answer), 2) gain controls for what namespaces will be checked for future projects, and 3) better control about how to display them in the Auto-complete list. Or...something(s). That darn a/c list gets so darn long, it needs some configurability.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@Craig's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78142043/2705042), I figured it out.

He mentioned Linq, so I searched and found [this post about Linq in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77398600/how-to-remove-linq-extension-methods-from-intellisense). It gave me some ideas, and after an hour of clicking around my systems to test & verify, I solved the issue.

I verified this on two different systems with Visual Studio 2019, and it works for projects in VB and C#.

The solution is as follows:

1. Click Tools > Options > Text Editor > Basic (or C#) (or both) > Intellisense.
2. If checked, uncheck the last option `Show items from unimported namespaces (experimental)`.
3. In the Project Properties, on the lower half of the window, uncheck `System.Linq`. Or for C#, remove the declaration `using System.Linq`.
4. The key and final step is to close/save/reopen the solution/project, and then the `<Extension>` methods will be gone. In fact, even that *button* will disappear from the Intellisense auto-complete list, as shown in the screenshot below.
5. **Unfortunately**, `System.Linq` will need to be unchecked/removed for every new project. Then close/reopen and the Extension methods will again be gone.
6. I could not find a way to make it go away permanently, even for new projects.

[image]

Comment: In VS 2022, the enclosing selection for the C# options is "In".  Seems like some sort of display bug where it should be "IntelliSense" same as in VB.  The option is still there, but no longer flagged as "experimental".